# How can i check if a folder is empty with specific files types and then to delete the folder?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to delete each folder that have no gif images files inside.
i don't mind if it's having text files or any other files, if the folder/s have no gif files delete it.

```
var dirsRad = Directory.GetDirectories(radarImagesFolder);
            var dirsSat = Directory.GetDirectories(satelliteImagesFolder);

            if(dirsRad.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach(string dir in dirsRad)
                {
                    if(!Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dir).Any())
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(dir, true);
                    }
                }
            }

            if(dirsSat.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string dir in dirsSat)
                {
                    if (!Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dir).Any())
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(dir, true);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem with this code is that if in the folder/s there is a text file it will not delete the folder/s , i want that even if there are any files that are not gif type delete the folder/s

Only if the folder/s contains gif images files then keep the folder/s.

Tried the code above but the folder/s some of them have a text file inside so it's not deleting the folder/s.

Comment: What if the directory contains sub directories and the sub directories have gifs but none in the base directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefilesystementries?view=net-7.0#system-io-directory-enumeratefilesystementries(system-string-system-string)) of the enumeration method you are using to only get files that end in `.gif`. If there aren't any, then delete the folder (including subdirectories and files).

This only applies to the current directory. If there are subdirectories of `dirsRad` with `.gif` files inside, they will be deleted. Exercise caution if that's not what you want.

It also assumes that a GIF file is simply identified by its lowercase extension. If you suspect you may have some GIF files that don't respect this, such as files written as `.GIF`, you'll have to make the method case-insensitive.

This translates to this simple change:

```
            if(dirsRad.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach(string dir in dirsRad)
                {
                    if(!Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dir, "*.gif").Any())
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(dir, true);
                    }
                }
            }
```